# compiler can't understand '_FILE_' why?

Tags: c, file, macros

I use Code::Blocks in C with C code
and have some errors ..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SQRT(num)    \
((num>0)    ?\
(sqrt(num)): \
(printf("the number is negative")))

int main() {
    printf("The file %s is executeD \n", _FILE_);
    printf("the sqrt of number %d is %f \n",8,SQRT(8));
    printf("the sqrt of number %d is %f \n",9,SQRT(9));
    printf("the sqrt of number %d is %f \n",-9,SQRT(-9));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There need to be *two* leading and trailing underscores. Is that a typo?

Comment: Also, you seem to think that it is the name of the executable, right? In addition, 0 is not negative, and the program will print 22 for the square root of -9.

Answer (score 7):

It is `__FILE__`, not `_FILE_`.

Answer (score 1):

The macro is `__FILE__` (double underscore in each side)

Answer (score 1):

Try it with a double underscore, eg: `__FILE__`